# Does a large amount of extraBufferCapacity in the SharedFlow cause memory leak?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

I am working on a chat application with MVVM architecture and I use `SharedFlow` to transfer incoming messages from `Repository` to `ViewModel`. When the user is offline and another user sends a large number of messages to him, as soon as the user is online, the messages are received one after the other in the `Repository` and need to be transferred to the `ViewModel` for display in the user interface. I first set the `extraBufferCapacity` value to 1 and saw that in this case only the first two messages are received in the `ViewModel`. Then I increased the `extraBufferCapacity` value to 6 and saw that the first 7 messages were transmitted to the `ViewModel`. Now if I increase the `extraBufferCapacity` value to the `Int.MAX_VALUE`, will it cause memory leak?

**Repository:**

```
object ChatRepo {
    private val _receiveMessageFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Message>(extraBufferCapacity = Int.MAX_VALUE)
    val receiveMessageFlow = _receiveMessageFlow.asSharedFlow()

    fun listen(socket: Socket) {
        socket.on(Config.ON_PV_MESSAGE, onPvMessage)
    }

    private val onPvMessage = Emitter.Listener { args ->
        val message = Gson().fromJson(args[0].toString(), Message::class.java)

        _receiveMessageFlow.tryEmit(message)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class ChatViewModel(var receiver: User) : ViewModel() {
    private val _messagesLive = MutableLiveData<Resource<MessageList>>()
    val messagesLive = _messagesLive as LiveData<Resource<MessageList>>

    init {
        observeReceivedMessage()
    }

    private fun observeReceivedMessage() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            ChatRepo.receiveMessageFlow.collect { message ->
                if (message.senderUid == receiver.uid) {
                    addMessage(message)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addMessage(message: Message) {
        val resource = _messagesLive.value ?: Resource.success(MessageList())
        val messageList = resource.data ?: MessageList()
        messageList.addMessageLast(message)
        _messagesLive.value = Resource.add(messageList, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What is a **memory leak** from Wikipedia:

> In computer science, a memory leak is a type of resource leak that
> occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations
> in a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released. A
> memory leak may also happen when an object is stored in memory but
> cannot be accessed by the running code.

According to your code you have `ChatRepo`, which is `object` (`Singleton`), the lifetime of `ChatRepo` is lifetime of the application. It has a field `receiveMessageFlow`, which can buffer some data, not consumed by any subscriber. If the only subscriber is in `ChatViewModel` and it no longer consumes the data, emitted by `receiveMessageFlow`, but `receiveMessageFlow` is still buffers some data, then in this case I would say there is a memory leak, because **memory which is no longer needed is not released**.